# User wallpaper the same as login wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits

Do you know any other solution for changing background to be the same as your login wallpaper, this where you choose user and log in.

I am the only user on my laptop, and I like the fact that my desktop have the same wallpapers in these two places.

I understand that when I am changing user desktop I am only change it as user,
and if I want to change login desktop I need to be root.

personally I do it by open terminal type `sudo nautlius` going to `/usr/share/backgrounds` copy file and change it`s name to one of the system wallpaper already is there and give to file right privileges.

Then I right click on screen and go to Change Desktop Background and choose my wallpaper file.

Comment: Are you using some derivative of Ubuntu like Ubuntu GNOME or Kubuntu? The usual Ubuntu uses LightDM with the Unity greeter, which should do that by default. Are you using an encrypted home directory?

Answer (score 1):

First copy your wallpaper to `/usr/share/backgrounds/` directory by the following command:

```
sudo cp /path/to/wallpaper/Image.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

Now switch to `xdg-open /usr/share/backgrounds/` directory and from there right-click on your wallpaper which you want to set as desktop wallpaper(This same wallpaper will be set automatically to login screen too), then select `Open with image viewer`.

Now right click on opened image in image viewer and select `set as wallpaper` from context menu.

Note: You have to set your wallpaper from/in `/usr/share/backgrounds` directory after coping your favorites images there. otherwise it doesn't work if you don't do that from/in backgrounds directory.

*Logoff and log back in and see the magic(Also it works if your home directory is encrypted).*

Answer (score 0):

Below steps will give lightdm user access to the X-Server and open dconf-Editor to change the settings of Unity Greeter.

Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below to install dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Run command to get the root user privilege:

```
sudo -i
```

Allow user lightdm to create a connection to the X server:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
```

Switch to user lightdm in this terminal window.

```
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
```

Now you can start the dconf-editor via this user by running:

```
dconf-editor
```

When the tool opens, navigate to com –> canonical –> unity-greeter. Then change the background value to your custom image and disable both draw-grid and draw-user-backgrounds